# How to get Spotify playlist JSON without user login

Tags: javascript, json, spotify

In my music player I am trying to load Spotify playlists. But it requires authentications. So user has to login to spotify in order to get authenticated.
Is there any way I can skip that ?!

```js
var code = "code";
var myurl = "http://example.com/callback/";
var mysecret = "cc2957f021a047169849c4r41e02f216";
var myid = "d05c7af0a091410fb67edb928f1177d3";
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize",
  data: {
    "client_id": myid,
    "response_type": code,
    "redirect_uri": myurl,

  },
  success: function(result) {
    var spotifyLink = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/119455481/playlists/53v6gfmQnXqLbmyZek2b7Q";
    $.getJSON(spotifyLink, function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The above code is how I try to `GET` data and load the JSON object. But I do not want it to ask users to login. 
Is there any way for that ?

Comment: I'm guessing the answer is either "no", and that it's hard to get a users playlist without knowing what user you're dealing with, or ... that the answer is in Spotify's documentation for the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a user's playlist authorization *is required* and you will not be able to do it without a user authorizing you or your application.  You'll need a valid access token generated by the user to permit you to access their data.

- https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlist/
- https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#authentication

Answer (score 1):

My answer is quite late, but I found this Github project which gets any Spotify playlist metadata in JSON returned via HTTP API . And No need for a Spotify API key. The JSON returned all information needed, eg : playlist cover image, album name, tracks ...

https://github.com/dantheman213/spotify-playlist-to-json